# Load the data to the texbot from the drop down menu

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Fellow experts,

I have the following text field:

```
<input type="text" id="url0" class="text_box" name="url">
```

And the following PHP code that load files to the drop down menu:

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<select name="s1">
      <option value="" selected="selected">-----</option>
  <?php 
       foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/files/*') as $filename){
       $filename = basename($filename);
       echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";
    }
?>

</select> 
</body>
</html>
```

When I select a data from the drop down menu, I would like to display it on the above text field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's simple with the hooking up the onchange event of jQuery

```
$("[name='s1']").change(function(evnt) {
  $("#url0").val(evnt.target.value);
});
```

jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/n8FSe/2/

Comment: I know how to do that in other languages Like .Net but have no idea how to do it with the script because I recently started working with it. Need fast modification of the script right now :)

Comment: I've just posted + jsFiddle. have a look.

Answer (score 4):

You can use change event to get your answer.

```
$("[name='s1']").change(){function(){
  $('#url0').val($(this).val());
});
```